# Disabling awt/swing debug (fine) log messages

Tags: java, swing, logging, awt

I'm using java logging to write log messages of my application to a log file and other destinations. Having set the log level to `FINE`, I also get (unwanted) messages from AWT/Swing, such as:

```
{0}, when grabbed {1}, contains {2}
```

and others. Looking at the JDK source code (see e.g. [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/awt/X11/XWindowPeer.java.html)), one sees that the name of the corresponding logger is `sun.awt.X11.grab.XWindowPeer`.

What I understood from the Java logging framework is that this logging handler should inherit its loglevel from its parents like `sun.awt`.

I tried the following:

```
Logger.getLogger("sun.awt").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

but the AWT/Swing debug messages still appear in the log output.

What's the recommended way of **programmatically** disabling these log messages (while still allowing `FINE` messages from other sources) ?

Comment: Please update your question to show how you are obtaining your logger instance and how you are calling it.

Comment: @AndreHolzner Did you find what you want? Would you please share?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to log the **messages of your own application**, you can disable all messages and then explicitly enable messages for your application:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("package.of.your.application").setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

Inside the properties-file for logging (e.g. logging.properties) this would be:

```
.level = OFF
package.of.your.application.level = ALL
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not find the getRootLogger() method in the Logger class any more. This is what works for me:

```
logger = Logger.getLogger("my.package");
Logger l = logger;
while (l != null) {
    l.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    l = l.getParent();
}            
logger.setLevel(Level.FINER);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. Searching on google this is the top url and I don't find a good source to a answer, so I will post mine :)

Assuming that Andre use the `java.util.logging` API, it's possible to add a `Handler` that will control the format of your log, using `setFormatter(Formatter newFormatter)`.

So I extended `Formatter` and checked if the class of the log contains java.awt, javax.swing or sun.awt.

```
class MyFormatLog extends Formatter {

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        if( !record.getSourceClassName().contains("java.awt") &&
        !record.getSourceClassName().contains("javax.swing.") &&
        !record.getSourceClassName().contains("sun.awt.") ) {
          //format my output...
        } else {
          return "";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Logger.getLogger("java.awt").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("sun.awt").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("javax.swing").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);