# Disabling graphics debugging in Swing

Tags: java, swing

How can I disable the Graphics debugging option in a java Swing project in Netbeans. Each time I run the project all the logs related to graphics are displayed on the command line. For instance:

```
Graphics(0-1) Enabling debug
    Graphics(0-1) Setting color: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=51]
    Graphics(0-1) Setting font: javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=SansSerif,name=sansserif,style=plain,size=12]
Graphics(2-1) Setting color: DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145
Graphics(2-1) Setting font: javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=SansSerif,name=sansserif,style=plain,size=12]
Graphics(2-1) Drawing string: "Date format is "YYY-MM-DD"" at: java.awt.Point[x=0,y=9]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling awt/swing debug (fine) log messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029454/disabling-awt-swing-debug-fine-log-messages)

Comment: Did you use `JComponent#setDebugGraphicsOptions` to enable the logging?

Comment: I think I have't done something in the code , but I am not sure if it was done by changing some properties in the properties of some component